# Forms and passing user actions

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a Form1 which calls Form2. Basing on the "Ok" click on Form2 I need to run some code in Form1. I am notifying the run base class that user pressed ok by the following method in the form2. `kanbanmultijob` is the instance of class  `KanbanMultiJob` which is behind my form2. So I am struck at a point where how do I retrieve or make use of `closedOk()` function in Form1 , which typically returns bool value basing on `closeOk()`?

```
public void closeOk()
{
    if (kanbanMultiJob.checkCloseDialog())
    {
         super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `form1` you called `form2` like this;

```
form2.run();
form2.wait();
```

You need to then check `form2` for `closedOk()`;

```
if(form2.closedOk())
{
  //Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I Always tend to do is creating a "context" object where I store the parameters that I need to throw around.

When running things in form 1, store the values in the context.
When closing the form, fetch your context object from form1 in form2. (As seen above)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should not make "work" in forms, work belongs to classes.

So go use the [Runbase Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa863262.aspx) or for AX 1012 the recommended [SysOperation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg862488.aspx). Make a action menu item and call that from your `Form1`.
The `Form2` is the dialog of your framework class.

I am not a fan boy the SysOperation framework, so in Runbase terms:

```
public Object dialog()
{
    return Dialog::newFormnameRunbase(formstr(Form2), this);
}
```

Then do whatever you need to do in the `run` method.

See the `tutorial_RunbaseForm` form and class to see how this works.